# how to install gerix on ubuntu 12.04 using backtrack repositories?

Tags: 12.04, installation, repository, software-sources

I got instructions [from here](http://www.noktec.be/archives/885), and I found several sites with similar instructions but somethig is wrong with the repositories on 12.04. This should work for 11.10 and previous versions.

Any ideas how to install backtrack repos and some back track apps on 12.04?

I read about downloading the .deb package for gerix and manually making the same folder structure that gerix uses on backtrack, then manually run the python script, but this way didn't work for me either.

How can I get gerix installed and working on my Ubuntu 12.04 system?

Comment: Please note that adding backtrack repository in ubuntu is dangerous ,It may break your s/m ,both ubuntu and backtrack are not respondible for it. So it is better to install backpack in another partition :)

Comment: in fact, is a good idea try Ubuntu and install VirtualBox and then inside the VM install BT

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/176298/22949) may help you, but if not, I recommend editing your question to provide more detailed information on all the procedures you tried and what went wrong, including the complete and exact text of any error messages.

Comment: Of course, people using this must understand what "under your own risk" sentence means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the terminal under Ubuntu 12.10/12.04/11.10 or older and run the following commands to add the BackTrack repository:

   ```
   wget -q http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/backtrack.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. To check if the repository is added correctly, you can try to install this BackTrack package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install backtrack-wallpapers
   ```

   Or you can search BackTrack applications from Ubuntu Software Center.
3. Last step is install Gerix:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gerix-wifi-cracker-ng
   ```
4. Don't forget run gerix as root.

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng/gerix.py
   ```

   Have fun using Gerix.

I tested this steps with success on 12.04 64bit.

Source:
[How To Add The BackTrack Repository To Ubuntu 12.10/12.04/11.10](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-add-backtrack-repository-to.html)

Comment: UPDATE: Since all steps I wrote,are working succefuly, It doesnt mean GERIX will work as expected, I have some problems detecting my own MAC Adresses, Imma not sure yet whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to try gerix, but did not want to add the backtrack repositories to my Ubuntu 12.04 sources. What I did:

```
wget http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/pool/testing/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt2_all.deb
```

gerix depends on python-qt3, which itself requires python-sip

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt3 python-sip
sudo dpkg -i gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt2_all.deb
```

While it may not be as simple as that when packages depend on Backtrack customized libraries or other packages, in this case it seems to work fine.